# Ошибка в java коде. (андроид приложение)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

В одной из папок приложения под андроид есть файл (а точнее несколько файлов) в одной и той-же ошибкой- "Unknown entity 'R'".

Для более точного примера приведу строку кода:

```
setContentView(R.layout.confirm);
```

где R-это и есть ошибка.

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить

Comment: Попробуйте почистить проект `Build -> Clean Project`, затем пересобрать `Build -> Rebuild Project`, можно еще попробовать заново синхронизировать проект `File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov `R` - это [особый класс для доступа к ресурсам](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources?hl=ru).

Comment: @AntonShchyrov вы вообще с разработкой под андроид на джаве имели дело?)))

Comment: @AntonShchyrov тогда все понятно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала открыть вкладку Build и выбрать Clean project. Если не помогло проверьте настройки Gradle. Проверяйте не только в файле, но и в File -> Project structure -> project -> Gradle version.

Вот мой gradle, может поможет вам:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.jone1.navigation_drawer"
            minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' }
```

и второй файл:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор не видит класса ресурсов в вашем приложени. Для устранения этой ошибки вам необходимо пересобрать проект:  `Build => Rebuild Project`.

Если ошибка сохраняется, посмотрите в логи, возможно сборка оказалась неудачной из-за других ошибок. Тогда добавьте лог ошибки в вопрос, посмотрим, что можно будет сделать :)